# RAID1 array won't start

Tags: raid, mdadm

Despite being able to get this to work before I cannot manage it this time.

I have a single disk raid array:

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine --verbose /dev/sdc**
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :      4980087 sectors at           63 (type fd)
Partition[1] :      1044225 sectors at      4980150 (type fd)
Partition[2] :   3900742650 sectors at      6281415 (type fd)


$ sudo mdadm --examine --verbose /dev/sdc3

/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a13d34aa:32872fcf:9675f885:aa092f93
           Name : MJ2CubeStation:3
  Creation Time : Sun Dec 18 22:22:56 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 1
 Avail Dev Size : 3900740602 (1860.02 GiB 1997.18 GB)
     Array Size : 1950370112 (1860.02 GiB 1997.18 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3900740224 (1860.02 GiB 1997.18 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 9435f6c2:42b4dd1c:69fddf4a:a7358539
    Update Time : Mon Mar 13 17:21:09 2017
       Checksum : 5494bd40 - correct
         Events : 18
   Device Role : Active device 32768
   Array State : . ('A' == active, '.' == missing)

$ more /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : inactive sdc3[0](S)
      1950370301 blocks super 1.2
unused devices: none
```

---

QUESTION: Any ideas on how to get the array started and mounted?

---

To try and assemble the array, I've done the following:

First I stopped the array md127:

```
$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md127 --verbose**
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
```

---

Then I've run fdisk:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd48b0300
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63     4980149     2490043+  fd  Linux RAID autodetect
/dev/sdc2         4980150     6024374      522112+  fd  Linux RAID autodetect
/dev/sdc3         6281415  3907024064  1950371325   fd  Linux RAID autodetect
```

---

Then I've run mdadm on /dev/sdc:

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine --verbose /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :      4980087 sectors at           63 (type fd)
Partition[1] :      1044225 sectors at      4980150 (type fd)
Partition[2] :   3900742650 sectors at      6281415 (type fd)
```

---

I then tried to assemble the array:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md127 /dev/sdc3
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md127
mdadm: /dev/sdc3 is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 32768.
mdadm: No suitable drives found for /dev/md127
```

---

QUESTION: Any ideas why I get the error "No suitable drives found for /dev/md127"?

---

I'm nervous about trying to use the build or assume-clean options for mdadm until I'm clear why I get the above error for assemble. Any input would be very welcome.

I've also run sudo `sgdisk --print /dev/sdc`

```
***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************
Disk /dev/sdc: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 8A621939-773C-44BB-952C-0705618461DF
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 262139 sectors (128.0 MiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              63         4980149   2.4 GiB     FD00  Linux RAID
   2         4980150         6024374   509.9 MiB   FD00  Linux RAID
   3         6281415      3907024064   1.8 TiB     FD00  Linux RAID
```

---

QUESTION: Is the invalid GPT a reason for the issues, should I try and fix this with gdisk?

---

Answer (score 0):

In the end the following worked.

```
sudo gparted
```

Once in gparted I selected the raid disk (sdc) and then performed a "Check" on the drive to ensure everything was ok.

After this the array still would not work.

I then used the following command to get the array to work:

```
sudo mdadm --run --verbose /dev/md127
```

This seemed to work and allowed my to mount the array and view the files:

```
sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/md127 /media/raid1
```

This did still return an error `No md superblock detected on /dev/md127` but at least I could access the files.

I am still unsure what really happened but it seems solved for now.